# New to programming, help in sum of matrix using for loop

Tags: python, matrix

Anyone pls help me in program to find out sum of elements in matrix using for loop.

This is my code.

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
total = 0
sha = np.shape(a)
for i in range(sha[0]):
    for j in range(sha[1]):
        total= total+a[i,j]
return total
```

Comment: sum([sum(i) for i in a]) use this

Comment: You neglected to specify what is wrong with your current implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use sum

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
sum([sum(i) for i in a])
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is nested list (list inside a list) you can refer to the following

```
a=[[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]
total=0
for i in a:
    total+=sum(i)
print(total)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]
Sum = 0    
sha = np.shape(a) 
for r in range(len(sha)):
    for c in range(len(sha)):
        sum = sum + a[r][c]

print(Sum)
```

**Sum is looped and calculated for r->row and c-> column**